# Females serving at the entrance of the tent of meeting?

Tags: women, mishkan-tabernacle, vayakhel

Shemot/Exodus 38:8 is speaking of woman serving or assembling at the tent of meeting. Who were these women, and what did they do there?

Answer (score 1):

Rashi comments and says that it refers to the women who would crowd at the entrance to bring their contributions to the building of the Mishkan. He also mentions some interesting things about the  bronze mirrors mentioned in the same passuk. You can see the whole Rashi [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.38.8?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en).

Comment: In 1 Samuel 2:22 the exact same words are used, so it seems that these females came there more often (even after they build the mishkan).

Comment: @Levi - Rashi also says these women would wait until they saw their birds being offered. See [here](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.2.22?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en).